# Slide remove view Gmail-like for API 7+

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I don't want to reinvent the wheel and this has been obviously already been done by Google in the Gmail app. I want to achieve effect identical to the finger slide message remove from gmail. It's also achieved in notofication bar in (you can remove notification by sliding it left or right)

I was wondering if I could get pointed in the right direction. Maybe this is described somewhere in google developers site.

What's most important I need it for API 7+.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to implement two different principles:

1. is the capture all the motion events to translate your view with the finger
2. use a [Gesture Detector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) to detect the onFling(), check if the fling is in the right direction, and if yes, apply whatever action you need.

Unfortunately I've never implemented such, so I can't show you any code. But hopefully that points you to the right direction.

Comment: As I stated in the question, I'd like to avoid reinventing the weheel if not neccessary :)

Comment: I understand what you said and you might wait for other answer if you want, but from my experience I don't believe there's a 'ready made' way to do it, and if there's it is implemented on Jelly Bean, meaning it won't fit your requirements. But it's really not that much work to calculate how many pixels the finger moved and apply it to the `leftMargin` of the view and make `if( flinger > X_pixels && to the right direction) remove view`.